# Where can I find API reference documentation?

Tags: application-development

Where can I find a complete API reference? I'm not sure where to get started beyond what was shown in the quickly video with Jono Bacon

Comment: API reference of what? What video?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to a comprehensive API reference for Ubuntu can be found at [the Resources section of the App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/). If you're making a normal `quickly` app, your most important references will be the [Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/), [Python](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/programming-languages/python/), and [Platform](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/api/) pages.

You can also get a manual for the `quickly` command line tool by typing:

```
man quickly
```